# Is there a convention as to placing a resistor before or after an LED?

Tags: led, current, resistors

We know that it makes no difference whether a resistor is placed "before" or "after" an LED in a circuit.

- [Changing the resistor to be in front or behind an LED doesn't affect brightness?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210524/changing-the-resistor-to-be-in-front-or-behind-an-led-doesnt-affect-brightness)
- [Does the resistor have to be before or after the component](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/253671/does-the-resistor-have-to-be-before-or-after-the-component)
- [Should Resistor be before or after an LED series](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340519/should-resistor-be-before-or-after-an-led-series/340520)

Is there a commonly used convention that encourages one or the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the possibility of a momentary short from one of the LED leads to ground (ground could be connected to the chassis)- perhaps it causes no problem if there is a remote resistor connected to Vdd but, if the LED is connected directly to Vdd, the short instantly destroys the LED. Or it shorts out the power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcA3yB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There may be other similar situations you can come up with. But really electrically it makes little or no difference one way or the other until you invoke such possibilities.